# Delete duplicate files with Windows batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have a program that automatically copies files to a directory, and if it creates a duplicate it will name it like so:

```
file with duplicate.xxx
file with duplicate - 1.xxx
file with duplicate - 2.xxx
```

I need a way to delete all the duplicates with a Windows batch file.

Something along the lines of:

```
FOR %f IN (C:\files\*.*) DO del "%f - 1"
```

However, that will not work because that would resolve to `file with duplicate - 1.xxx - 1`

Comment: a)Try for /r  to go through directories.   b)%~nf instead of %f will get the filename without the extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to delete all the files with a name that ends in `- ?`, then you were close.

Try this:

```
FOR %%f IN ("C:\files\* - ?.*") DO del "%%f"
```

You will need to double up the percent signs if you are running it from a batch file. And test with an `echo` instead of a `del` first.

Comment: I was overthinking it, you're absolutey right... there's no reason to base it off the original file name when all duplicates are guaranteed to end in " - [some number]". Though I didn't know about the ? selector... do batch files accept regex?

Comment: @Chris Batch files do not accept regular expressions, the * is not a regex * and the ? is not a regex ? you probably haven't fiddled with regexes that much. a*b if it was a regex would match b since * in regex matches 0 or more of the char before. In cmd * and ? are more intuitive, * means any sequence of char, and ? means one char.

Comment: @Chris Sobolewski, regex? I wish. :) It's simple wildcards, * for any number of any character, ? for any single character.

Comment: @Chris furthermore, I suppose you can skip the whole FOR and just do the DEL. Since DEL can take wildcards.  Interestingly DEL even has a /S switch so if you wanted to go through subdirectories, you wouldn't even need a FOR /R.

Answer (score 3):

No need to the `FOR`, `del` can accept wildcards. Try:

```
del "c:\files\* - 1.xxx"
```

Will match anything with the suffix " - 1.xxx" in the directory.