# Batch file delete duplicates, nested once deep

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, duplicate

Yes, I did see: [Delete duplicate files with Windows batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/334507/delete-duplicate-files-with-windows-batch-file)

But I was unable to modify it to check each subfolder of that I specify, I have:

```
del "c:\...\Pictures\*\*-001.*"
```

But it doesn't like it. I only need to go one folder deep (each subfolder is a month) and I don't need to check the `Pictures\` root.

I've tried this:

```
FOR %%F IN ("C:\...\Pictures\") DO FOR %%f IN ("C:\...\Pictures\%%F\*-001.JPG") del "%%f"
```

But that still isn't correct. Can anyone lend me a hand? I've very limited experience in batch files.

Comment: The question, as above, is how can I modify that line to delete duplicate files in every subfolder of `Pictures\`, not just 'loose' files in that folder itself.

Comment: That now odd looking comment above was in response to someone asking "what is the question".

Comment: Why can't you just use windows search in Pictures to search for *001? Or `del *-001.jpg /s`

Answer (score 1):

Set your real `%startfolder%` and look at the output. If it is good, remove `echo` before `del`:

```
@echo off &SETLOCAL
SET "startfolder=."

FOR /r "%startfolder%" %%i IN (*) DO call:doit "%%~i"
goto:eof

:doit
SET "fname=%~nx1"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "fsize=!$%fname%!"
IF DEFINED $!fname! (
     ENDLOCAL
     IF "%fsize%"=="%~z1" ECHO DEL "%~1"
) ELSE (
     ENDLOCAL
     SET "$%~nx1=%~z1"
)
goto:eof
```

The code doesn't delete if filesizes are different.

Comment: Thanks for response - output not correct though. I don't fully understand your code, but nowhere does it look for `-001` in the filename, it's those I want to remove. There's not many, they're just spread out, so I can forego a filesize check. Just delete anything ending `-001.JPG`.

Comment: You can change the code: `FOR /r "%startfolder%" %%i IN (*-001.jpg) DO call:doit "%%~i"` to get only JPG's. And sorry, this is my last visit here. The board told me for log in I have to disable my AdBlock. But I don't do that. You can put a new question at stackoverflow, if you want so.

Comment: Still not correct. Thanks for the help - I just went through manually in Picasa. You spend that long on trying to script it.. you may as well just be manual about it!

Comment: @Endoro I have adblock enabled with most draconian settings and still can browse SU fine. Perhaps worthy of a question on meta