# Easy way to delete duplicate files in a folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, duplicate

I have a folder with lots of images, where each image file has a duplicate file in the form abc.jpg and abc-1.jpg (where the latter is the duplicate file). Is there an easy way to select and delete the duplicate files?

If there is no easy way in the Windows UI, then is there at least a simple command to do this using the command line?

I really don't want to delete them one-by-one and I don't want to download software to do this either.

Comment: Can you go into Command Prompt and type `del *-1.jpg`? (Try `dir *-1.jpg` first to see what you get.)

Comment: @G-Man So there's no way to do this in the UI?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete duplicate files with Windows batch file](http://superuser.com/questions/334507/delete-duplicate-files-with-windows-batch-file)

Comment: If they were all modified at the same time, you might be able to sort on Modified/Created date, then delete them all.  But that's not a sure thing.

Comment: There are softwares' that will do the job correctly rather than you relying on Windows. I advise against just by deleting with wildcards such as *1.jpg. What if the original file which does not have a copy has the name abc1.jpg. How would  Windows 7 know that all *1.jpg files have a file without the "1" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this through the Windows interface (the GUI), then,
using Windows Explorer, go to the directory where your files are:

[image: full listing of directory]

Then click in the Search box and type `*-1.jpg`:

[image: search results for "*-1.jpg"]

Verify that these are the files you want to delete, and delete them. 
(You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all the files in the Search Results window.)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use file explorer that comes with windows and go to the folder where the files are stored and in the search box type or copy abc -  and delete the results
the reason I said abc - is beacuse windows adds the - sing to abc with a number after it
original file abc.jpg copy the file name to the folder will result in abc -1.jpg then the next copy will be abc -2.jpg if you have a thousand copies of that file name most of the answers here would not work properly

Comment: 'abc-' will select ALL of your photos.  I believe you'll want to search for '*1.jpg' or '-1.jpg'.

Answer (score 0):

from a command prompt:

```
cd <yourphotodirectory>
del *1.jpg
```

Please backup your files before deleting anything.